# when using boost library, should I link to mt or normal version of library?

Tags: boost

when I use boost library, I found for each library, usually it contains two versions.

for example, regex.a and regex-mt.a, which library I should link against? why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mt` is the thread-safe version. If your code uses threads, link the `-mt` version. Otherwise, link the regular one.